# What do you call the act of answering a question in a unsatisfactory way so that the we're compelled to ask another question?

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

What do you call the act of answering a question in a unsatisfactory way so that the we're compelled to ask another question? Is there an idiom or word associated with the action?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more explanation than that. Is the person being *evasive*? *Stupid*? *Deceptive*? *Passive-aggressive*? *Ignorant*? There are too many possible reasons for the situation.

Comment: An example of what you're trying to say would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is not one single word for this. It depends on the situation.

*coy* - showing reluctance, shy, modest
*evasive* - tending or seeking to evade; characterized by evasion: *an evasive answer*
*passive-aggressive* - personality characterized by indirect resistance to the demands of others
*curt* - rudely brief in speech or abrupt in manner
*terse* - of manner or speech: abruptly or brusquely short; curt
*stupid* - lacking ordinary keenness of mind
*dumb* - lacking intelligence or good judgment
*ignorant* - lacking in knowledge or training; unlearned
*laconic* - using few words; expressing much in few words; concise: *a laconic reply*
*unhelpful* - Not providing help or assistance; not helpful

Answer (score 1):

The commonest idiom is "giving [someone] the runaround."

Answer (score 0):

Both Mary’s and Sam’s answers give possible words and phrases based on your question’s ambiguity. The word ambiguous is probably the most succinct.